# Unique PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I check if the values are unique in an array based on the key value? Below is the out put of the array. I want to remove duplicate values based on the "id" key. If you check below, the 2nd & 3rd array are same except for the "role" value. Because of this, array_unique is not working on this array.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1521422' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'David Alvarado' (length=14)
      'role' => string 'associate producer  ' (length=20)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '0098210' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'Cristian Bostanescu' (length=19)
      'role' => string 'line producer: Romania  (as Cristi Bostanescu)' (length=46)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1266015' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'Bruno Hoefler' (length=13)
      'role' => string 'co-producer  ' (length=13)
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1266015' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'Bruno Hoefler' (length=13)
      'role' => string 'executive producer  ' (length=20)
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1672379' (length=7)
      'name' => string 'Alwyn Kushner' (length=13)
      'role' => string 'associate producer  ' (length=20)
```

Comment: Can't you solve this on the database level?

Comment: ok can you show us how you want the array to look ?

Comment: Which of the duplicates gets deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'text' => 'a'),
    array('id' => 2, 'text' => 'b'),
    array('id' => 1, 'text' => 'c'),
    array('id' => 3, 'text' => 'd')
);
$array = array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    static $found = array();
    if (isset($found[$item['id']])) return false;
    $found[$item['id']] = true;
    return true;
});

var_dump($array);
```

This works as of PHP 5.3 (because of the closure and static statement).

cf. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php for more information. I tested the statement within loops, it works there as well.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, because you are only storing the key once for each entry. +1

Comment: this works...thanks everyone for helping....never though that i will get so many reply is such a short time....

Comment: @BhaskarWankhede You're welcome, thats what StackOverflow is for :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to implement a variation of `array_unique` that does what you want:

```
function array_unique_multi($arr,$key='id') {
    // $arr is the array to work on
    // $key is the key to make unique by
    $ret = Array();
    foreach($arr as $v) {
        if( !isset($ret[$v[$key]])) $ret[$v[$key]] = $k;
    }
    return array_values($ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
// assuming $arr is your original array
$narr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
   //$narr[json_encode($value)] = $key;
   if (!array_key_exists($value["id"], $narr))
      $narr[$value["id"]] = $key;
}
$narr = array_flip($narr);
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
   if (!array_key_exists($key, $narr))
      unset($arr[$key]);
}
print_r($arr); // will have no duplicates
```